# Why replacing a return statement with a method that contains a return statement is not possible?

Tags: c#

The code sample below will throw "Not All Paths Return a Value "

```
   public static Validation Validate()
    {
       Validation invalid = new Validation()
       InvalidResult(invalid); // why removing the return keyword is not possible??
    }

    public static Validation InvalidResult(Validation invalid)
    {
        return invalid; // the return comes from here
    }
```

Comment: The `Validate` method has to `return` a `Validation` object. It's right there in the signature. So you need to `return` something. IIRC, (at least some versions of) vb would let you implicitly return the last value.

Comment: You have to return the result of the method. `return InvalidResult(invalid);` Otherwise how to know which value to return.

Comment: In short, any method that *doesn't* have the return type of `void` has to have a `return` statement. And it has to have one for every code path. That's just the way c# works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the C# language will not implicitly use the last value returned as a return statement, you must be explicit about it.

```
public static Validation Validate()
{
   Validation invalid = new Validation()
   return InvalidResult(invalid);
}
```

The only place the C# language allows for a implicit return is in a  [Expression Lambda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx#Anchor_0).

```
Func<Validation, Validation> example = (invalid) => InvalidResult(invalid);
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply put; `Validate` isn't returning anything, if you remove the `return` statement.

When `InvalidResult` returns, you're back inside the `Validate` function.  Now what?  `Validate` still needs to `return` something.

The answer: you need to return the result from the `InvalidResult` function:

```
public static Validation Validate()
{
    Validation invalid = new Validation()
    return InvalidResult(invalid);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're in the function where the return statement is called, the control of the program returns to the point where you called the function and you are expected to return a `Validation` type object. I hope that helped a little.